# R: Find the number of UNIQUE characters in a string

Tags: regex, r

I am looking to find real v. bogus identification numbers (think social security #, phone #, etc.) in a data set that is user-provided, and therefore messy.

Some users are purposely entering false information, like "idk", "fu", 123456, or 222222.

I can pretty easily filter out the words, but I'd like to get a little fancier and grab more of the obviously false information.

Conceptually, I'd like to remove numbers that, say, have nearly every digit unique, and nearly every digit the same.  So numbers like 2220222 and 123451 would be removed.

This needs to run fairly fast, and not be a huge memory hog, so performing inner loops on each entry isn't really viable.  I was hoping / thinking that there's got to be a clever way with regex's to do this.

Here is a strawman of what I'd like to have happen:

```
filter.func(my.str.array, 2, 2)
### Returns a logical array of length "my.str.array" with "TRUE" meaning that
### it would not be filtered, and "FALSE" that a filtering rule was broken

### the "2" and "2" are, respectively:
### First "2":  the min # of acceptable non-unique values (e.g., to catch 123456)
### Second "2": the min # of acceptable non-duplicated values (to catch 222222)
```

Thanks!

Comment: Your question is a good one, but what you are trying to do with the solution is awful! :P

Comment: @Hugh, sorry, I don't understand what you mean.  There is no nefarious work going on here.  We have user-submitted data, and I am just getting (an approximate) sense of how much of it I can trust.  There is no snooping, nor is there any expectation of a perfectly and theoretically valid solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here I use `strsplit` to split up a word into characters; then I use `table` to count the characters.

```
filter.func<-function(x, mindup=2, mindiff=2) {
    spt<-lapply(strsplit(x,""), table)
    sapply(spt, function(x) {sum(x>1)>=mindup & sum(x>0)>=mindiff})
}

filter.func(c("22222","123456","234356"),2,2)
# [1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

Might be better to test with more positive and negative values.

Comment: Wow... thanks so much @MrFlick! I cannot believe such an elegant answer was given so quickly!